# GRUB splashimage

Tags: linux, grub-legacy

I am using leagcy GRUB (0.97) on a system running linux kernel 2.6.31. I am using a GRUB splash image from /boot/grub/menu.lst. I see that the splashimage goes away once the GRUB menu selection is made and the INIT process starts. Is there a way that I can continue to display this image when INIT begins to run?

EDIT: I cant use fbsplash or plymouth since these dont compile with legacy kernels.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not unless you can tell the kernel/init to use a splash image; once GRUB loads the kernel its work is done and it relinquishes all control of the system to the kernel (which in turns calls `init` when it's ready to proceed)

I admit I've never tried any of them, but [splashy](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/splashy/) seems well supported.

... Also, 2.6.31 is "legacy" now?

Comment: 2.6.31 is definitely old and [no longer supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).